# Check params validity before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to verify if the model could be saved with a specific params but without saving it

```
event_params = {:user => @current_user.id, :id => id, :value => value}
```

If I wanted to save it I could verify it easily with something like

```
x = e.update_attributes(event_params) if x.true? .... end
```

I have read that I could use [**assign_attributes**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes) that would basically do the same as update_attributes but without saving.

The problem is that with the [**assign_attributes**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes) it always returns nil, so I think I have no way to verify it the params would be valid or not on the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `valid?` method on any instance of a model object, to have it go through validations and verify if this can be persisted. Note that this doesn't guarantee persistence as you might have other constraints at the database level.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F

Comment: Allright, I think that using the assign_attributes (that returns always nil) and after that the .valid? I can know if the change is valid or not (depending on if it returns true / false)

Comment: Yes, `object.errors.empty?` will be true if it passes validation after calling `valid?`